# How to detect the malware app

Tags: security, malware

I am a developer which working on security related area.Recently I 
met a little problem. If I got a app such as android .apk or IOS .ipa. 
How can I check whether it has malicious actions?
    The first thought came to my mind is to check its manifest. To see 
which kind of permission it has requested. But this general method can 
not detect some actions such as record the screen snapshot or record 
user tap position on screen.
    Then I switched to search how app store and google play check the 
app which submitted by developers. Turns out that they first check the 
certificate or signature of the app to make sure it has been published 
by trusted organization. Then statically check the system permission 
that the app requested.
    I guess there must be some in-depth detection method or theory 
which used by google and apple to make sure their app is safe to 
download. Can anyone provide me some useful information or website 
link that I can learn from?
    Thank you.